# Retrieve Wikipedia page title when performing full text search in Wikidata API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to search a term using [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php), and retrieve a list of corresponding entities identifiers and related Wikipedia page titles (if available).
I'm currently using the following URL:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srinterwiki&srsearch=nyc

however parameter 'srinterwiki', documented [here](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch), does not return any Wikipedia link.

Many many thanks

Ps: I know this can be achieved using 'wbsearchentities' with 'props' parameter, but it does not perform a full-text search. Indeed, it is not capable of returning the same results of the Wikdata search box as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170179/wikidata-api-wbsearchentities-why-are-results-not-the-same-in-python-than-in-wi).

Answer (score 0):

`srinterwiki` returns interwiki search results (that is, search results for the same search query from other wikis), not interwiki links for the normal search results. Pass the results to `wbgetentities` to get sitelinks.

(Normally you would use [generators](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) for this kind of thing, unfortunately `wbgetentities` does not support generators.)